# How to abort a merge in mercurial?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, merge, dvcs, undo

I goofed up a merge.  I'd like to revert then try again.
Is there a way to revert a merge before it is committed?

`hg revert` doesn't do what I'd like, it only reverts the text of the files.  Mercurial aborts my second attempt at merging and complains original merge is still uncommitted.

Is there a way to undo a merge after an `hg merge` command but before it's committed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to abandon a hg merge?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570087/how-to-abandon-a-hg-merge)

Answer (score 113, accepted):

`hg update -C <one of the two merge changesets>`

Comment: Simple, efficient and, I think, the best way to do it! :D

Comment: @JonL. - Yes, `--clean` is a synonym for `-C`. I'm not sure which changeset `.` will refer to, but it will always be one of the two merged changesets.

Comment: @Omnifarious, cleaning `.` should clean to whatever revision you were on prior to initiating the merge. So if you were at r42, attempted to merge with r43, failed, cleaned, you'd be back on a pristine r42.

Comment: `hg update --clean` works, as `.` seems to be the the implicit default - it's [not explicitly documented](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#update) though.

Comment: @JoelPurra: The meaning of `.` in the context of a merge is rather ambiguous.

Comment: @Omnifarious: seemed to default to the working copy changeset that was there before any other changeset was `merge`'d *in* as the second parent. Good enough for me =)

Comment: @JoelPurra: I should look in the code to see if that's the explicit intention. The other possibility I could see is the default being the changeset with the lowest or highest valued hash (which is essentially picking one randomly).

Answer (score 43):

After you do `hg merge`, but before `hg commit`, your working copy has two parents: the first parent is the changeset you had updated to before the merge and the second parent is the changeset you are merging with. Mercurial will not let you do `hg merge` again as long as your working copy has two parents.

You have two options on how to proceed:

1. If you want to abort the merge and get back to where you started, then do

   ```
   hg update -C .
   ```

   This will update the working copy to match the first parent: the `.` always denotes the first parent of the working copy.
2. If you want to *re-merge* some files then do

   ```
   hg resolve fileA fileB
   ```

   This will re-launch the merge tools just as when you did `hg merge`. The resolve command is good if you find out at `hg merge`-time that your merge tools are configured badly: fix the configuration and run `hg resolve --all`. You can run `hg resolve` as many times as you want until you are satisfied with the merge.

Answer (score 2):

Today there is `hg merge --abort`. See `hg help merge`.