# Mercurial - basic process to revert a merge and try again

Tags: mercurial, merge

We merge using this process:

```
cd c:\myapp
hg pull ssh://hg/myapp-1_0_1
hg merge
```

Now sometimes we mess up the merge or sometimes we get an error (ie: "can't merge file xxx - file in use").  Usually I just delete my c:\myapp repo, re-clone from the remote master repo and start over.  This works but it's a pain.  What is a better way?

I've read about using `hg update -C` but I'm not clear on the process.  So you'd do `hg update -C`, this would delete the merged files but keep the changesets that were pulled down, and then you'd issue the `hg merge` command again and try again?

---

**Update** Regarding the related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570087/how-to-abandon-a-hg-merge): `hg update -C` still keeps the changesets in the repo which were pulled down with `hg pull` - how can you get rid of those?

Comment: The `C` in `hg update -C` is not a placeholder for a changeset. It's just ye old capital third letter of the alphabet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to abandon a hg merge?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570087/how-to-abandon-a-hg-merge)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`hg update -C` is just perfect. Why would you want to get rid of the pulled changesets? Because the update command updates to the head of the pulled changes? If this is your problem with the pulled changes, run `hg update -C <revision-of-your-local-head>` and don't care about the pulled changes, probably you'll pull them again at some point anyway. After the update proceed your work or try the merge again.

However, if your really want to get rid of pulled changes, use the [strip](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Strip) command.

Answer (score 3):

See this post [How to abandon a hg merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570087/how-to-abandon-a-hg-merge)

Comment: My memory is not at its best today... When I saw this question I went looking through my own *asked* questions, because I knew I had asked it before. Apparently I had *answered* it. I think I need more coffee...