# Mercurial Getting out of a bad merge

Tags: mercurial

I just merged branch A into B, and for some reason the merge did not go well. I want to revert B back to where it was before the merge and try again like it never happened before. I was thinking of just doing

```
hg clone myrepo newrepo -r A -r 12345
```

where 12345 is the revision number before B's bad merge commit

I think this works, but I have a lot of other branches (most of which are closed using commit --close-branch) and this puts those branches back to an inactive state.

Is there a way to clone everything except revision 123456 or something? (where 123456 is the bad commit on B)

Comment: Did you push the commit with the bad merge in it somewhere?

Comment: @Lasse no, it is local only to me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to abandon an uncommitted hg merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570087/how-to-abandon-an-uncommitted-hg-merge)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you have not pushed the merge changeset to any public location, the easiest solution is to use the `hg strip` command that comes with the Mercurial Queues (i.e. `mq`) extension.

From the [wiki](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PruningDeadBranches#Using_strip):

> `hg strip rev` removes the `rev` revision
>   and all its descendants from a
>   repository. To remove an unwanted
>   branch, you would specify the first
>   revision specific to that branch. By
>   default, `hg strip` will place a backup
>   in the `.hg/strip-backup/` directory. If
>   strip turned out to be a bad idea, you
>   can restore with hg unbundle
>   `.hg/strip-backup/filename.`

Comment: Strip not only removes the branch and its revisions, but also any merges from that branch into another, which may make sense, but screwed me over.

Answer (score 2):

It might not be as nice as hg rollback, but usually what I do is update to head A, merge in previous head B, check that I got it right this time, and then [dummy-merge](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Keep_.22My.22_or_.22Their.22_files_when_doing_a_merge) away the bad merge.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I'm understanding your situation correctly.  If I am you should be able to update to the revision of B before the merge, give that revision a new branch name, merge A in to it, and continue on.  You'll probably want to mark the original B branch as closed.

```
$ hg up 12345  #12345 is the revision of B prior to the merge
$ hg branch B-take2
$ hg merge A
$ hg commit -m 'merge A in to B-take2'

$ hg up B
$ hg commit --close-branch -m 'mark original B branch as closed'
```

Comment: I thought about this, but I thought surely there must be another way without having to mess up my branch names

Comment: I don't think there is.  Probably my biggest issue with mercurial is its permanency around branch names.

Comment: I suppose you could apply the reverse of the diff between the revision before the merge and the head of the branch.  That will effectively reverse the changes introduced as part of the merge and leave you on the same branch.  It could get messy, but it might be worth a shot.

Comment: You don't need to name the branches involved in this rescue-operation.

Comment: @Lasse how do you make the original branch follow the newly created anonymous branch instead of the path I want to get rid of?

Comment: Let me rephrase. You don't need to *create new branch names*. You can stick with the branches you had. In any case, since you haven't pushed anywhere, just strip off the original merge commit, and redo the merge properly and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Is it too late to use the [hg rollback](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/finding-and-fixing-mistakes.html) command?  If so, try the [hg backout](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/finding-and-fixing-mistakes.html#id392218) command.

Comment: backout doesn't work well with merges, you won't end up with two heads afterwards, you have to pick one of them. Rollback, Strip, or a partial clone, is the way to go.